Alert in Resource Definition Notebook for Packet
I recently discovered the "Resource Definition Notebook" which helps considerably with the development of paclets. It enables you to check the coding of the various files associated and also build and deploy the paclet.
When performing checking, the wl code is checked and an "alert" is found which I cannot understand. The alert is message is "Optional occurs before OptionsPattern and may bind arguments intended for OptionsPattern. (Lxxx,Cyy)
The highlighted code typically has the following pattern:
Option[f]={"a"->1}
f[b_,OptionsPattern[]]:={b,OptionValue["a"]}

It is not clear to me what is wrong?

If it gave that warning for that code, it seems like a bug in the code inspector.  You should see that alert if you had the definition f[b_:2, OptionsPattern[]] := ...

Jason: Thanks very much for responding. Apologies I oversimplified my question too much and left out the :2 default for b. Why should that give the alert? Indeed what does the alert really mean?

I believe the error message is quite descriptive. Think about what happens if you give a rule as the first argument:
ClearAll[f];

Options[f] = {a -> 1};
f[b_ : 2, OptionsPattern[]] := {b, OptionValue[a]}

f[10]
(* {10, 1} *)      (* As expected *)

f[10, a -> 5]
(* {10, 5} *)      (* As expected *)

f[a -> 5]
(* {a -> 5, 1} *)  (* You probably did not want this! *)

As you can see, if the first argument is a rule, it will grab it into b instead of into options. That is why it warns you about this.
You can prevent this (and probably also the warning?) by explicitly setting the type of the first argument (which, obviously, should not be a Rule or a List):
Options[f] = {a -> 1};
f[b_Integer : 2, OptionsPattern[]] := {b, OptionValue[a]}
f[a -> 5]
(* {2, 5} *)


Thanks very much. I had not considered populating the function with an incorrect argument in the way suggested.
